# Oracle text Content Search?

Tags: oracle, text, indexing

I use Oracle Text indexing for content searching and i want to know it is possible to use map network drive as my file data store. I want to use below query to search within documents. Here FURL stores the path name of the documents and DT_001 is my table. I saved path as "\SEVER-PC\map_ser\text.txt" but result was null . help me

```
 SELECT  SCORE(1), FURL FROM DT_001
 WHERE CONTAINS(FURL, 'Oracle',1) > 0
 ORDER BY SCORE(1) DESC;
```

Comment: thank you for editing my question but any one have a guess??

Answer (score 0):

to overcome this problem we have to use UNC path as ;

```
 "\\pc_name\shared_folder\doc name with extension"
```

Ex:
     "\\SEVER-PC\map_ser\text.txt"

then you have to start oracle listener and oracle DB service (mine XE) as log on user in Winodws os who map the network directory to the system. you can do this 
 Start --> Run --> Services.msc --> OracleServiceXXXX ---> Properties --> Logon and then restarting the service . if you followed these steps well its working fine .
This method tested on Winodws only.